# Chart.js xaxis formatter changes the value shown in the chart

Tags: chart.js

I'm creating a simple visualization that shows the evolution of the Temperature in the past 24h. It is shown in the picture.

[image]

In the x axis I'm showing the hours and I'm trying to format them so that 10 -> 10:00, and so on.

However, when I include the ticks.callback in the options, the chat shows as follows: it always starts at 0:00 while the correct chat, at this particular time starts at 12.

```
ticks: {
    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
        return `${value}:00`;
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see I've been able to format the y axis, but there is something different with the x axis.

This is the whole configuration of the chart, in case the error is there:

```
        const labels = this.extractLabels(this.props.data);
        const dataPoints = this.extractData(this.props.data);
        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Avg. Temperature',
                data: dataPoints,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                tension: 0.1
            }]
        };
        const options = {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    grace: '5%',
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Temperature',
                        font: {
                            size: 16
                        }
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                            return value + ' ºC';
                        }
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Date',
                        font: {
                            size: 16
                        }
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                            return `${value}:00`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        const config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: options,
        };

        this.temperatureChart = new Chart(this.chartRef.current, config);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the tip in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats):

> The category axis, which is the default x-axis for line and bar charts, uses the index as internal data format. For accessing the label, use this.getLabelForValue(value). API: getLabelForValue

so to get the right display value your callback needs to be this:

```js
ticks: {
    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
        return `${this.getLabelForValue(value)}:00`;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error that getLabelForValue doesn't exist. When I try let _this = this as any, the error is moved to runtime. What should this refer to in this context or what might be set in tsconfig to enable the function to be callable?

Comment: This should work fine, did you copy paste my code?

Comment: @stephen I got the same error but I have found the solution. I was using an arrow function "() => {}", and now i am using the classic "function() {}" declaration and the error disappeared.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: Thanks Toundrake, same.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the labels, but in my opinion a better solution would be to implement a [Time cartesian axis.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis) This would allow you to add more data without making changes to the labels. You would need to include a [time adapter](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters) to make it work.

**config:**

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: { 
      scales: {
          xAxis: {
                type: 'time',
                
                ticks: {
                    source: 'labels', // get ticks from given labels
                },

                time: {
                    minUnit: 'minute', // smallest time format

                    displayFormats: {
                        minute: "HH:mm",
                        hour: "dd/MM HH:mm",
                        day: "dd/MM",
                        week: "dd/MM",
                        month: "MMMM yyyy",
                        quarter: 'MMMM yyyy',
                        year: "yyyy",
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    }
};
```

Here is a fiddle to show you how this would look: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/bvx59ndy/)

Comment: Thanks Jesper, this is more complex and elaborated solution, yet it seems more elegant and reusable. I'll give it a try