# Chart JS version 3+. How to get a tick's label in a tick callback function?

Tags: chart.js

I was very confused about this, and just now seem to have figured this out. Didn't see much documentation on this, so I figured I'd respond to my own question here for future results for others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js xaxis formatter changes the value shown in the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771677/chart-js-xaxis-formatter-changes-the-value-shown-in-the-chart)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the first two arguments will be the index of said tick.
The third argument seems to be the currently rendered ticks as an object. This is NOT helpful in getting the data.labels of the chart js object.
The getLabelForValue function will get the data.label for said tick index.

```
callback: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    let labelOfTick = this.getLabelForValue(label)
    //Do some logic
    return something
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, the first argument is the value, although on category scales you need to transform it first, second arg is the index of the tick and the third argument is all the ticks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    ticks: {
      callback(val:any, index:any): string {
        return index % 2 === 0 && typeof val === 'number' ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working for me on `"chart.js": "^4.3.0"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).